# Hide 'out of stock' products in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

Under "Products" and "Inventory" I have checked the following setting:
"Hide out of stock items from the catalog"

Now all sold out products are hidden in the archive/category view. So far so good.

The problem is that the hidden (out of stock) products are counted per page. So if there are 3 products that are sold out on the first page, only the ones in stock are showing (6).

It also seems that these "hidden" products still are searchable as well, and visible through the different widgets.

Any ideas how to fix this? I mean to REALLY hide products that are out of stock. Or do I need to manuallly remove them?

Comment: @super9 I have updated my answer with something I also overlooked the first time I set up and imported my products into WooCommerce. Not really a programming solution, but easily overlooked when just importing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note to self: Always read the changelog from developer.

Found the answer here: http://develop.woothemes.com/woocommerce/2014/02/solving-common-issues-after-updating-to-woocommerce-2-1/#category-counts-incorrect

> In case the product counts for categories are showing a too high or
>   too low number, after updating to WooCommerce 2.1 there is an easy
>   workaround.
>
> Go to the ‘Tools’ tab inside the WooCommerce > System Status of your
>   WordPress administration panel. Here you first use the ‘Recount terms’
>   button and after that use the ‘Clear transients’ button. This will
>   force the system to recount all the products the next time a category
>   is loaded.

Update: Also remember that it is not enough to change stock quantity to 0. You must also set "Stock status" to "Out of stock". If not the product will be counted in the shop, even if there are no products in stock.

Answer (score 13):

You can try adding this to your theme's functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {

if ( ! $q->is_main_query() ) return;
if ( ! $q->is_post_type_archive() ) return;
if ( ! is_admin() ) {


$q->set( 'meta_query', array(array(
    'key'       => '_stock_status',
    'value'     => 'outofstock',
    'compare'   => 'NOT IN'
)));

}

remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

}
```

I modified the code from this URL: http://www.wptaskforce.com/how-to-exclude-one-or-more-category-in-woocommerce-shop-page/

Saved here again just in case that site goes offline: (this code excludes certain product categories)

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {

if ( ! $q->is_main_query() ) return;
if ( ! $q->is_post_type_archive() ) return;
if ( ! is_admin() ) {

$q->set( 'tax_query', array(array(
'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
'field' => 'slug',
'terms' => array( 'PUT YOUR CATEGORY HERE' ), // Don't display products in the membership category on the shop page . For multiple category , separate it with comma.
'operator' => 'NOT IN'
)));

}



remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately didn't work. Out of stock products are still searchable, and counted in pagination. Since the developers didn't add this to the plugin, I guess there unfortunately ain't any quick fixes for this.

Comment: Great solution that's still working four years later. A couple things to consider: (1) Doesn't check the type of query/post type so would apply to custom post types. (2) Overwrites any meta_query already applied. Both easily fixed and depend on your own situation, of course!

Answer (score 8):

I found easier way, if anybody is still looking for hiding out of stock products in woocommerce, follow these easy steps without editing html !

1. Go to WooCommerce -> Settings
2. Go to Inventory
3. There's a checkbox that says something about our problem, however it goes in english :-) you'll find what you need
4. Save

Comment: Klaudia... sorry, that selection will only hide products from the archive (catalog). A search will return out-of-stock items that aren't seen in the archive, even if the settings identify a preference to hide out-of-stock items.

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

that will only work if you are using the official woocommerce shortcodes , but if you creating a page with visual composer and using  customized plugins or 3rd party plugins or shortcodes ,  the first step is to for the query that run from the loop then you modify it to something like this

```
$params = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'post_type' => array('product', 'product_variation'),
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_stock_status',
                'value' => 'instock'
            )
        )
);
```

the most important part that you have to be sure of is

```
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_stock_status',
            'value' => 'instock'
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

Steps to Hide Out of Stock Products

1. Go to **WooCommerce -> Settings submenu** in the WordPress dashboard
2. Click on the **Products Tab > Inventory sub-tab**
3. Check the option **Out Of Stock Visibility** that hides the out of stock products

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I know that this question was asked long time ago but the **solution** of the problem is now different, so I post this for people who had the same problem as I did. Tested on WooCommerce 5.3.0

**SOLUTION:**
First of all make sure that checkbox "Hide products that are out of stock" in Woocomerce > Settings is **unchecked** than add this PHP code to your child-theme functions.php file:

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_query', 'show_only_instock_products');

function show_only_instock_products($query) {
        $meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );
        $meta_query[] = array(
                'key'       => '_stock_status',
                'compare'   => '=',
                'value'     => 'instock'
        );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
}
```

It works well in my store, which is integrated with a wholesaler, where inventory levels are updated every hour and there are thousands of products.

Comment: How to hide out-of-stock products for logged-out users only?

Comment: @ZeroCode Do you mean logged-out users in general? Or non-admins?

Comment: non-admins only

Answer (score 0):

You can place PHP snippet at the bottom of your child theme functions.php file.

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_woocommerce_product_query');

function custom_woocommerce_product_query($q)
    {
        if (!is_admin())
        {
            $oos_query = new WP_Query(['meta_query' => [['key' => '_stock_status', 'value' => 'outofstock', 'compare' => '=', ], ], 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => - 1, 'fields' => 'ids', ]);
            $exclude_ids = $oos_query->posts;
    
            $q->set('post__not_in', $exclude_ids);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer will be more helpfull if you explain it and add coments

Comment: Added the snippet to functions.php but out of stock product kept showing on search result

Comment: How do I apply this, so if I create a button for someone to click, it hides out of stock products?

Thanks for the explanations so far. :)