# how to exclude out of stock product by size by using yith ajax navigation filter woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, filtering

I am using YITH ajax navigation filter for a woocomerce store. Here is a problem arise. My product size is different like 6,7,8,9,10. and i have put quantity for different size. My problem is when my product "out of stock" in any size although this product show when I filter. Suppose my product size 10 is out of stock but it is show when I filter size 10. I have already set woocommere "Hide out of stock" and recount terms and clear transient. But not working. Please help.

Comment: this link will help you . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480982/hide-out-of-stock-products-in-woocommerce

Comment: I have seen before this post and worked but not working @Noman

Comment: No. Tried to follow number 1 answar